# Using a reduction ufunc in agg

Tags: python-polars

How do I use a ufunc that reduces to a scalar in the context of aggregation? For example, summarizing a table using `numpy.trapz`:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(id=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], t=[2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 14], y=[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
df.groupby('id').agg(pl.map(['t', 'y'], np.trapz))
# Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I have made sure that we now throw an error hinting the solution instead of the core dump: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/3052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: as of Polars 0.13.18, the apply method converts Numpy datatypes to Polars datatypes without requiring the Numpy item method.

Use `apply` in a groupby context (rather than `map`).

In this case, the numpy trapz function takes only one positional parameter (y)

```py
numpy.trapz(y, x=None, dx=1.0, axis=- 1)
```

So, we'll need to specify the x keyword parameter explicitly in our call.  (I also assumed that you meant for your `y` column to be mapped as the `y` parameter, and your `t` column to be mapped as the `x` parameter in the call to numpy.)

The Series 'y' and 't' will be passed as a list of Series to the lambda function, so we'll use indices to indicate which column maps to which numpy parameter.

One additional wrinkle, numpy returns a value of type `numpy.float64`, rather than a Python float.

```py
type(np.trapz([0, 1, 1], x=[2, 4, 5]))
```

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Presently, the `apply` function in Polars will not automatically convert a `numpy.float64` to `polars.Float64`.  To remedy this, we'll use the numpy `item` method to have numpy return a Python float, rather than a `numpy.float64`.

```py
type(np.trapz([0, 1, 1], x=[2, 4, 5]).item())
```

```
<class 'float'>
```

With this in hand, we can now write our `apply` statement.

```py
df.groupby("id").agg(
    pl.apply(
        ["y", "t"],
        lambda lst: np.trapz(y=lst[0], x=lst[1]).item()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ y    │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 13.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ 2.0  │
└─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Yep, `apply` is the solution. I would prefer that that I got a numeric column rather than an object, but `return_dtype=pl.datatypes.Float64` does not appear to do anything. Am I misunderstanding that argument?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Numpy is returning a value of type <class 'numpy.float64'>, which polars is not automatically converting to type polars.Float64.  There's an easy fix.  I'll revise my answer so that apply returns a column of type polars.Float64.